# How to find the intersection points

Tags: calculus

I want to find the points at which the ellipsoid $\frac{x^2}{4}+y^2+z^2=1$ intersects at one of the hyperboloids of the family $x^2+y^2-(z+1)^2=e^2$.

Multiplying the equation $\frac{x^2}{4}+y^2+z^2=1$ by $4$ we have $x^2+4y^2+4z^2=4$. Addind the latter to $-x^2-y^2+(z+1)^2=-e^2$ we get $3y^2+5z^2+2z=3-e^2$.

What else could we do in order to find the intersection points?

Comment: You have eliminated $x$. The equation you are left with involves just $y$ and $z$. This represents a curve in the $yz$-plane. For each point of this curve you can substitute the $y$ and $z$ value in the ellipsoid's equation getting corresponding $x$ value.  This describes  the intersection of the two surfaces you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can not find intersecting "points" in your case,

The equation you find is,
$$3y^2+5z^2+2z=3-e^2$$
this represents a Hyperbola and hence all the points on this Hyperbola are intersecting points of this ellipsoid and hyperboloid.

These are the only intersecting points you can find with these two equations because you have **2 equations** and **3 variables** so you can reduce only **one** variable (if it not further reducible with these equations as in your case).

Comment: Your use of $3D$ is misleading - the ellipsoid is a $2D$ surface. The intersection of $2$ of these such surfaces can also have any finite cardinality (meaning it's not necessarily a 'figure' or closed curve as you stated).

Comment: @Zestylemonzi  thanku i edited my answer and i googled and learned about it , thanku again for pointing my mistake........

Comment: Geat - glad I could help :)